# ubuntu16.04 mysql The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:

Tags: mysql

I just uninstalled and reinstalled mysql in my Ubuntu. After installation, setting root and the password, I tried to login through "mysql -u root -p", but it yields with the following:

> The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:  *
>   mysql-client-core-5.7  * mariadb-client-core-10.0 Try: sudo apt
>   install

I then try "sudo apt install mysql-client-core-5.7"
It shows "

> mysql-client-core-5.7 is already the newest version
>   (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2).

". However it still does not work. Each time I type "mysql", it still yields:

> The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:  *
>   mysql-client-core-5.7  * mariadb-client-core-10.0 Try: sudo apt
>   install

I think that my MySQL server is running good and I have already connected it with my emma client. Anyone has any idea about this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install mysql-client-5.7` ?

Comment: @Jos Yes I did. And it shows "mysql-client-core-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)". And it keeps show "The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages: * mysql-client-core-5.7 * mariadb-client-core-10.0 Try: sudo apt install <selected package>" as long as I type "mysql"

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt remove mysql-client-core-5.7` and, if that succeeds, `sudo apt install mysql-client-5.7`.

Comment: worse. Now I try to start mysql and it shows "Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service is masked." Now my MySQL is shut down.

Comment: Do `systemctl unmask mysql.service` and then `service mysql start`.

Comment: @Jos I can start the server. But when I type "mysql -u root -p" with the password, it shows "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

Comment: OK so you unmasked the service and installed `mysql`. Is your server running? Please do `service mysql status`.

Comment: @Jos Something like "mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-04-03 16:38:58 CST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6444 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1088 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
"

Comment: @Jos I just reinstall MySQL again. Everything go back to normal. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove completely mysql. Try this:

```
    sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
    sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
    sudo apt-get autoremove
    sudo apt-get autoclean
```

After that you can install again:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```